# Should I use session variables to prevent infinite web form popups?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have a web application that allows a user to view family members.

When the user clicks on a family member, it displays the member's basic info.  There is also a grid displaying that family member's related family members. (e.g. User can click on the Father link.  From that popup, they can then click on the Father's Father link, then click on the Father's Father's Grandson link, etc.).

To reduce the number of popups that appear on the screen, I want to prevent the user from continually clicking on family links past three members.

What is the best way to keep track on how many data forms have popped up?  Or can this reliably be done with a web application?

Comment: How are the popups implemented?

Comment: Let them have as many as they like? Anyway, I prefer ViewState (for WebForms). It *works really well* if used correctly. Of course this question is so vague as to what technology is being used or how...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course there are many ways to do this, all probably valid.  I would maintain a number on each window (not global).  I'd use the Querystring of each popup to increment and push this number onto new windows.  Each window will increment this count by one and embed it in the links on its page.  Once the count is 2 in a window, don't render anymore hyperlinks in that window.  That way they only have 3 open at a time, but can still close one to go back a level, and then click a different link to continue.

Answer (score 1):

I think session sounds like overkill. I would write the count to a hidden field on the page.
This is a very flexible technique. 
It supports both client side and server side based loading of the popups

Comment: I would just write to a stand alone hidden field. That way it's easier to get it out . Especially if the popups are javascript based